# Determining error in the channel using Silverlight proxy client for WCF service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, asynchronous, proxy, wcf-client

I'm creating Silverlight proxy client for WCF service using async pattern:

```
public class ProductService : ClientBase<IProductService> {

    public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs<Product>> GetProductCompleted;

    public void GetProductAsync(string productName) {
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = Channel.BeginGetProduct(productName, GetProductCallback, null);
    }

    private void GetProductCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
        Product product = Channel.EndGetProduct(asyncResult);
        if (GetProductCompleted != null)
            GetProductCompleted(this, new DataEventArgs<Product>(product));
    }
}
```

How can I get know if an error occurred in the channel during performing request to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EndGetProduct` ought to throw the error when called, so place a `try..catch` around it.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I was expecting behavior similar to proxy's behavior generated by slsvcutil.exe, where you should explicitly check Error property of EventArgs object.

Comment: @sam: Even when using the eventargs accessing the Result property will throw the error so I generally just use a try..catch anyway and ignore the Error property